# Polygon Offset/ Minkowski sum with a sphere algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, polygon, computational-geometry

I am looking for a accurate polygon offset algorithm for 3D polygons, convex and non convex. This can also be achieved with Minkowski sum with a sphere. I know CGAL provide a minkowski package. 
However, is there an easy algorithm that I can implement to achieve this task of polygon offse in 3D.

Thanks.

Cheers,
CB

Comment: The task is inherently difficult. There is no "easy algorithm." It is easier if your "3D polygons" (the term is ambiguous) are either convex polyhedra in 3D or planar polygons in 2D.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What I have is surface data of different objects which are not necessarily convex and present holes.

Answer (score 2):

There are easy-ish approaches for offsetting convex polyhedra -- you just move each polygon along its normal, convert edges into cylindrical arcs, and vertices into spherical sectors. For concave geometry, though, this will produce intersecting and degenerate faces. If all you want to do is render then that's okay... but if you intend to do anything interesting with the offset geometry, you really need the big guns provided by things like CGAL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, should look into CGAL.